# WithLatestFrom($foo) not emitting when $foo emits, possibly because of the use of merge

Tags: rxjs

I am implementing an observable which can be subscribed to before it is "assigned" Think of it like hoisting an observable definition so I dont have to worry about the order in which I create observables derived from other observables, I call it a ColdSubject.

ColdSubject works fine (I can add observables to it, and only when somebody subscribes to the ColdObservable do its operators get evaluated).

However `withLatestFrom` will never emit while waiting for `obs$`, despite the observable it's "waiting for" emitting to a subscriber several times!

```
export class ColdSubject<T> {
    // If you subscribe to this before an observable has been added to $acc, you will be notified as soon as one is added, and if you subscribe to this after an observable is added to acc$ you will also be notified 

    public obs$: Observable<T>;
    public acc$ = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<T>>(merge());
    constructor() {
      this.obs$ = this.acc$.pipe(switchMap(v => v));
    }
    addObservable(newObservable: Observable<T>) {
      this.acc$.next(merge(this.acc$.getValue(), newObservable))
    }
}

const foo = new ColdSubject<number>();

# I know this observable is waiting for withLatestFrom because "Tap yeet" is logged
of('yeet').pipe(
  tap(v => console.log(`tap ${v}`)),
  withLatestFrom(foo.obs$)
).subscribe(v => {
  console.log(`WithLatestFrom ${v}`);
});

# This observable will begin emitting 5 seconds into the script, because I wait 5 seconds to subscribe to it
foo.addObservable(
  interval(1000).pipe(
    take(5),
    tap(v => console.log(`Interval ${v}`))
    )
);

# Subscribe 5 seconds into script start, so I know that my ColdSubject only evaluates its observables once they're subscribed to
setTimeout(
  () => foo.obs$.subscribe(v => console.log(`Subscribe ${v}`)),
  5000
);
```

Why does `foo.obs$` emit several times, while the operation waiting for its latest value not emit?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6-opeartors-m6uyqj?file=index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L132) one can see that `withLatestFrom` is  triggered by`_next` which is fired by the source Observable calling `next`:

```js
protected _next(value: T) {
  if (this.toRespond.length === 0) {

    /**
    *   value - emitted by the source Observable
    *   ...this.values - emitted by the Observables passed to `withLatestFrom`
    */
    const args = [value, ...this.values];

    if (this.project) {
      this._tryProject(args);
    } else {
      this.destination.next(args);
    }
  }
}
```

Your issue is that your source completes right away, while the Observable passed to `withLatestFrom` has not emitted yet. by the time `foo.obs` emits, your source Observable has long since completed.

What I would recommend of using  in your case is `combineLatest` as demonstrated below:

```js
combineLatest(of("yeet"), foo.obs$)
  .pipe(
    tap(v => console.log(`tap ${v}`)),
  )
  .subscribe(v => {});
```

Comment: I just came back to the question to recommend using combineLatest

Answer (score 0):

of('yeet') emits and is complete so withLatestFrom will complete as the source is complete.

Change your subscription to

```
of('yeet').pipe(
  tap(v => console.log(`tap ${v}`)),
  withLatestFrom(foo.obs$)
).subscribe({ complete: () => console.log('yeet complete') });
```

and you will see it is infact complete.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6-opeartors-2nuam1?file=index.ts